# Get number in a string using bash and regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu

I need to get the number behind score in a ascii file containing the following string:

> ```
> iteration 32: score=0.126462
> ```

I want to do it in bash.
So the output should be:

> ```
> 0.126462
> ```

I know I have to use regular expressions however I'm not very familiar with it and I could not fix my problem after hours.
Thanks

Edit: Some of the solutions are not working for me unfortunatly since I'm not hard coding the string in some variable but passing in in a pipe.

> cat kMeans.init-1.log | tail -2 | head -1 | CODE_SHOULD_GO_HERE

Comment: What about awk, sed ,grep?

Comment: As I said I'm not familiar with regular expressions. Examples I found dealt with the number separated by spaces from the matching string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure bash solution.

```
$ [[ "iteration 32: score=0.126462" =~ score=([0-9.]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
0.126462
```

Through grep,

```
$ echo 'iteration 32: score=0.126462' | grep -oP 'score=\K[\d.]+'
0.126462
```

Comment: The string "iteration 32: score=0.126462" is passed by some prior operations using "head" and "tail". So I  would need to get the argument of the command via pipe "|" and not as a hard coded string

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use regular expressions, but if you must:

```
string='iteration 32: score=0.126462'
if [[ $string =~ score=([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)$ ]]; then
    number=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    printf 'Found number: %s\n' "$number"
else
    printf 'No number found.\n'
fi
```

Without regular expression:

```
string='iteration 32: score=0.126462'
if [[ $string = *score=+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
    number=${string##*score=}
    printf 'Found number: %s\n' "$number"
else
    printf 'No number found.\n'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep -E -m 1 'score=([0-9.]+)' your_file
```

will return only the first match `0.126462`

or try `your_file | sed "s/\result=([0-9.]\+\)/\1/"`

Comment: This seems to just highlight "score=0.126462" what I need would be to extract the pure number such that I could print into a text file